# Struggling to retrieve information from Firebase using RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    ingredientsList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new IngredientAdapter(this, ingredientsList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



    dbIngredients = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ingredients"); //error is here

    dbIngredients.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
    // recyclerView.bringToFront();
}
```

The error im having is at the line i have stipulated by getReference("Ingredients");. My database in firebase has Ingredients and then under Ingredients is the name. But it will not retrieve anything.

---

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (3.0.0). Please report to firebase-database-client@google.com
    at com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidPlatform$1$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:98)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7037)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp$IdTokenListener;
    at com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidPlatform.newAuthTokenProvider(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:112)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.ensureAuthTokenProvider(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:246)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.initServices(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:98)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.freeze(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:77)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.RepoManager.createLocalRepo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:92)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.RepoManager.createRepo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:42)
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.ensureRepo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:357)
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:201)
    at com.example.mycheflogin.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:44) // this is the line of the getReference();
```

Comment: Please post stack trace and database Structure.

Comment: Please post your gradle and dependencies.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo stacktrace and database screenshot available in edit log.

Comment: @Ashish I cannot see any stacktrace or database screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo you can read [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4d652591-aa5e-4139-90b3-e9ab44e0665c/view-source) of Stackoverflow

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that you're using a very old version of the Firebase SDK (`3.0.0`). Please upgrade to the latest version.